# Spectre Dispersion and Damage Type

Tags: dota-2

So spectre's dispersion reduces all incoming damage by 22%...

Now I'm wondering, does it work for all types of incoming damage, including pure damage, magical damage, physical damage, HP removal...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume reducing the damage and reflecting the damage is the same amount of damage. So the same rules apply.

On the wiki:
http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Spectre

**Dispersion reflects the damage after damage block, magic resistance and armor reductions.**

Reflected damage is not felt by Spectre, effectively reducing every incoming damage by 10%/14%/18%/22%.

Reflected damage is not shared between enemies. All of them take the full reflected damage.

The damage dealt decreases linearly from a 300 radius to a 1000 radiusfrom Spectre.

This is how much damage Dispersion Dispersion will deal to enemies at certain distances:

300 radius: 10%/14%/18%/22% of dealt damage

475 radius: 7.5%/10.5%/13.5%/16.5% of dealt damage

650 radius: 5%/7%/9%/11% of dealt damage

825 radius: 2.5%/3.5%/4.5%/5.5% of dealt damage

The damage from Dispersion Dispersion does not trigger any on-damage effects. This means that the following spells and items will not react on Dispersion Dispersion damage:

```
Aphotic Shield  Aphotic Shield, Backtrack ,
Blade Mail , Blink Dagger , Bottle,
Bristleback ability  , Clarity , Cold Snap , 
Corrosive Skin , Echo Stomp , Fatal Bonds ,    
Healing Salve , Heart of Tarrasque , 
Kraken Shell , Living Armor , Mana Shield , Mjollnir , 
Nightmare , Open Wounds , Orchid Malevolence ,
Recall , Refraction , Return , Soul Assumption ,
Spiked Carapace , Spin Web , Summon Spirit Bear 
Urn of Shadows.
```